# How to change mat-form-field border color in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am trying to change the border color for my text box in Angular Material. Right now there are three different colors (for *hover*, *focus*, and *idle*). How can I change these colors?

I want them different than my theme.

```
<mat-form-field id="test" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label class="test2">Outline form field</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="name">
</mat-form-field>
```

There are options to change the font size, but I can't seem to figure out the color:

```
mat-form-field.mat-form-field {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: red;
}
```

The color attribute here changes nothing.

Answer (score 16):

You may have noticed there are two different behaviours in mat-form-field concerning border.

It has one border colour when you hover on it and when you click on it (of course if you have changed the appearance before that).

For example, if you are using:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" [color]="primary" appearance="outline"> </mat-form-field>
```

When you hover over it you will see one colour, but when you click on it the border colour it will take will be from:

> [color]="primary"

If you want to change it, follow the guidelines Angular Material provides on styling. If you want to change the colour which is when you hover over it (since ::ng-deep is deprecated) you would need to add ViewEncapsulation into your component:

```
@Component({
...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And add the following to your style class:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: white;
}
```

This will change the colour of the element when you hover over it.

P.S.: if you have as well a suffix or a prefix element to override those colour just add this:

```
  mat-form-field.mat-form-field {
    color:white;
  }
```

P.S.: if you want to change the colour of the border when the element is not being hovered over or touched this will help:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: black;
}
```

**UPDATE 2019-05-02:**

To change the primary/secondary colour you can use http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%233f51b5 to generate your own and apply it in Theming.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Angular Material documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#theming), you can only set the color to the primary/accent colors and warn (i.e. red).

> `<mat-form-field>` has a color property which can be set to `primary`, `accent`, or `warn`. This will set the color of the form field underline and floating label based on the theme colors of your app.

---

Note: You can use some [CSS hacks](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) using `::ng-deep`, but that will be eventually be deprecated. Or you can mess around with the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component declaration to avoid having to use `::ng-deep`, but [read up on that](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html) because it causes other styling issues.

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-underline, ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: ::ng-deep is already depreciated, so this does not work. I would think there would be another css hack.

Comment: @Jonathan, I should have said that `::ng-deep` is decprecated, but still supported (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). I mentioned it was a hack/workaround, not a solution.  `mat-form-field` is its own component and thus gets its own style encapsulation.  You have to either work with what the Angular Material team gives you to work with (the color property), change the encapsulation of your parent component, or resort to CSS hacks.

Comment: The color property that the Angular team gives you will change all text box and all elements according to the theme. How do I change the encapsulation of my parent component? How would I resort to a CSS hack that works ?

Comment: @Jonathan, the articles in my answer will explain both how to use the `::ng-deep` CSS hack and how to change the encapsulation of a component.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to change the colors of Angular Material styles without resorting to the deprecated `::ng-deep`. Increase the specificity of the selector, and place the styles in your main/root stylesheet.

So if you have the following in your component:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field class="my-form-field">
    <input matInput placeholder="My Input">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

You can add the following styles to your main stylesheet:

```
/** Overrides underline color **/
.my-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline,
.my-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-ripple,
.my-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-focused
    .mat-form-field-underline,
.my-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-focused
    .mat-form-field-ripple {
    background-color: white;
}

/** Overrides label color **/
.my-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-label,
.my-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-focused
    .mat-form-field-label {
    color: white;
}

/** Overrides caret & text color **/
.my-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-input-element {
    caret-color: white;
  color: white;
}
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhvgdn?file=styles.css)

This isn't the recommended way of styling your entire app. For that you should just [create your own theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components). But it can make sense for a one-off component, for instance, where your background color is clashing with your available theme colors.

Comment: Welcome StackOverflow and Thanks! My problem solved. Angular Material is lack of explanation on SCSS, they even not have any example and pass the documentation link at each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here by this CSS you can change color/border thickness on hover:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
    border: 0.2px solid #666;
    opacity: 1;

    .mat-form-field-outline-start,
    .mat-form-field-outline-gap,
    .mat-form-field-outline-end {
        border: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'xxxx-dialog',
  templateUrl: './xxxx-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xxxx-dialog.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Check by inspecting the browser property that is affecting your element. Take that class and edit in your local CSS content.

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding: .4375em 0;
    width: 650px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that works for me is this:

```css
// mat-input focused color
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
  border: none !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 1;

  .mat-form-field-outline-start {
    border-top: 2px solid #1976d2 !important;
    border-left: 2px solid #1976d2 !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1976d2 !important;
  }
  .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1976d2 !important;
  }
  .mat-form-field-outline-end {
    border-top: 2px solid #1976d2 !important;
    border-right: 2px solid #1976d2 !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1976d2 !important;
  }
}
.mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  border-top: 2px solid #1976d2 !important;
}
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-can-float.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order (please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61402013/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar), not here in comments).

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your form-field-appearance-example.css:

```
// mat-icon-stepper selected color change 
::ng-deep .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-selected, .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-done, .mat-step-header .mat-step-icon-state-edit {
    background-color: blue!important;
}

//input outline color
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: blue!important;
}

//mat-input focused color
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: blue!important;
}

// mat-input error outline color
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline-thick{
    color: blue!important;
    opacity: 0.8!important;
}

// mat-input carent color
::ng-deep .mat-input-element {
    caret-color: blue!important;
}

// mat-input error carent color
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-invalid .mat-input-element, .mat-warn .mat-input-element {
    caret-color: blue!important;
}

// mat-label normal state style
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
    color: blue!important;
}

// mat-label focused style
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
    color: blue!important;
}

// mat-label error style
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-label {
    color: blue!important;
}
```

I hope this would help others.

Answer (score -5):

Go to Node_modules → @angular → material → prebuilt-themes → indigo-pink.css →
Find mat-form-filed-appearance-outline, and then change your color.

Comment: In what context? Is it referring to a particular tool (please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57214420/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar), not here in comments)?