# Angular Material - how to change border color during hover?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I tried all I could think of, using ::ng-deep, but I cannot target the border color during hover!

I can change it correctly in Dev Tools, but I Cannot apply it in the code, the selector seems always wrong!

this is the html:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="userNameInput">
        <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
        <input matInput #email type="email" placeholder="mail@mail.com" (keyup.enter)="loadUserInfo(email.value)">
      </mat-form-field>
```

by default the hover border-color is black!

Comment: Which of the elements' border-color do you want to change? Should the change on hover be statically (CSS only) or be dynamically based on some state of your app (involves JavaScript logic)?

Comment: I just want a static color!

Comment: Already answered using _specificity_ and `ViewEncapsulation` instead of deprecated `::ng-deep` hacks, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50786787

Comment: @hc_dev thank you! this not only solved my issue, but I removed all the ::ng-deep I was using, thank you for the info

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your css/scss file,

```
.userNameInput:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

if doesn't work! try,

```
.userNameInput:hover {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

Hope this helps

have a look at this,

[image]

Comment: this is a mat-form-field, this doesnt and cannot work. ::ng-deep must be used

Comment: In latest documentation it's mentioned that it's been deprecated. you can refer here https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: using !important should work for you, have you tried that?

Comment: it didnt work, the right solution was from the person that commented my initial post, that works well