# mat-form-field legacy change border color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm currently trying to change the underline of a legacy `mat-form-field`. For now I test a lot, including the following :

```css
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-underline,
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy .mat-form-field-ripple,
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-focused .mat-form-field-underline,
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple,
.mat-form-field-appearance-legacy.mat-focused .mat-form-field-legacy-thick {
    color: red
}
```

But my underline still remain in blue. Here is the definition of my `mat-input-field`:

```html
<mat-form-field class="block">
    <input type="text" matInput placeholder="{{ 'AUTH.username' | translate }}" formControlName="username" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="submittedForm && loginForm.controls.username.invalid">{{ getErrorMessage('username') }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `::ng-deep`? Otherwise it accepts `color` input, but color needs to be in palette.

Comment: I tried with ::ng-deep without success :/ The weird things is that if I custom the `mat-form-field-appearance-outline` I can get it working :/

Comment: Does this solve your problem: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50786787/how-to-change-mat-form-field-border-color-in-angular-material)

Comment: Is this a one-off change or do you want this styling to be applied to other mat-form-fields?